# SQLAlchemy: an efficient/better select by primary keys?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using MySQL.

I have an user table in declarative mode:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(u'id', Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(u'name', String(50))
```

When I have a list of users identifiers, I fetch them with:

```
user_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
users = Session.query(User).filter(User.id.in_(user_ids)).all()
```

I dislike using `in_` because I think I learned it has bad performance on indexed fields.  Is that true?

Is there a better way doing that query?  How would I write this query using `OR` with SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternate to using an `in` clause is to `or` the IDs:

```
id = 1 or id = 2 or id = 3
```

If there is just a few you might gain some speed going that way.

From the "[Common Filter Operators](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators)" documentation:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
filter(or_(User.name == 'ed', User.name == 'wendy'))
```

You don't say what DBM you are using but your administrator might be your best asset here. The best way to know what construct to use is to analyze the query and try a couple different ones so you know how well your particular database engine handles them. No matter what database you are using, if it supports `or` or `in`, you are probably going to gain a lot of speed using those instead of looping over all the IDs you need and making individual queries.

It might turn out that worrying about whether to use `in` or another construct is not going to make a big difference to the overall speed of the application in comparison to changing other parts of the code. Database engines are getting pretty crafty about optimizing simple queries so you'll get good performance as long as your query is sensible.

One of the things we have to learn about programming is to get the code working well first, then test and optimize if there are problems. Often we assume we know where the bottleneck is but a profiling tool will show we were wrong. Using a profiler and benchmark tools can help narrow down the problem areas and show what are the best ways to speed up whatever needs tweaking.

Comment: New URL for those docs: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators

Answer (score 4):

A lot of performance woes are database engine dependent. The rest of this post will deal with MySQL.

An `IN()` clause can have bad performance on an indexed field, but it will not in the example that you gave. Up to a certain number of `user_ids`, your query will be the fastest possible. However, at some point, it becomes faster to put the `user_ids` into a temporary table and `join` against it. You can see more details about the performance of `IN()` vs a temporary table in MySQL in "[Passing parameters in MySQL: IN list vs. temporary table](http://explainextended.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-in-mysql-in-list-vs-temporary-table/)".

If that list of `user_ids` is based on some attribute of the users (such as being admins or being invalid) then you could add a field to your User table and avoid this problem altogether.

Answer (score 0):

@Hadrien (the OP) used:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import or_
user_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
clauses = or_( *[User.user_id==x for x in users] )
users = Session.query(User).filter(clauses).all()
```