# How to construct a slightly more complex filter using "or_" or "and_" in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, filter, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do a very simple search from a list of terms

```
terms = ['term1', 'term2', 'term3']
```

How do I programmatically go through the list of terms and construct the conditions from the list of terms so that I can make the query using `filter` and `or_` or `_and`?

```
query.filter(or_(#something constructed from terms))
```

Answer (score 33):

If you have a list of terms and want to find rows where a field matches one of them, then you could use the `in_()` method:

```
terms = ['term1', 'term2', 'term3']
query.filter(Cls.field.in_(terms))
```

If you want to do something more complex, then `or_()` and `and_()` take `ClauseElement` objects as parameters. ClauseElement and its subclasses basically represent the SQL [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of your query. Typically, you create clause elements by invoking a comparison operator on Column or InstrumentedAttribute objects:

```
# Create the clause element
clause = (users_table.columns['name'] == "something")
#    you can also use the shorthand users_table.c.name

# The clause is a binary expression ...
print(type(clause))
#    <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.expression._BinaryExpression'>
# ... that compares a column for equality with a bound value.
print(type(clause.left), clause.operator, type(clause.right))
#    <class 'sqlalchemy.schema.Column'>, <built-in function eq>,
#    <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.expression._BindParamClause'>

# str() compiles it to SQL
print(str(clause)) 
# users.name = ?

# You can also do that with ORM attributes
clause = (User.name == "something")
print(str(clause))
# users.name = ?
```

You can handle clause elements representing your conditions like any Python objects, put them into lists, compose them into other clause elements, etc. So you can do something like this:

```
# Collect the separate conditions to a list
conditions = []
for term in terms:
    conditions.append(User.name == term)

# Combine them with or to a BooleanClauseList
condition = or_(*conditions)

# Can now use the clause element as a predicate in queries
query = query.filter(condition)
# or to view the SQL fragment
print(str(condition))
#    users.name = ? OR users.name = ? OR users.name = ?
```

Comment: Why do you have to put parentheses around the SQL in `clause = (User.name == "something")`?

Comment: @Noumenon The parentheses around `(User.name == "something")` are optional.

Answer (score 18):

Assuming that your `terms` variable contains valid SQL statement fragments, you can simply pass `terms` preceded by an asterisk to `or_` or `and_`:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.sql import and_, or_
>>> terms = ["name='spam'", "email='spam@eggs.com'"]
>>> print or_(*terms)
name='spam' OR email='spam@eggs.com'
>>> print and_(*terms)
name='spam' AND email='spam@eggs.com'
```

Note that this assumes that `terms` contains only *valid* and *properly escaped* SQL fragments, so this is potentially unsafe if a malicious user can access `terms` somehow.

Instead of building SQL fragments yourself, you should let SQLAlchemy build parameterised SQL queries using other methods from `sqlalchemy.sql`. I don't know whether you have prepared `Table` objects for your tables or not; if so, assume that you have a variable called `users` which is an instance of `Table` and it describes your `users` table in the database. Then you can do the following:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, or_, and_
terms = [users.c.name == 'spam', users.c.email == 'spam@eggs.com']
query = select([users], and_(*terms))
for row in conn.execute(query):
    # do whatever you want here
```

Here, `users.c.name == 'spam'` will create an `sqlalchemy.sql.expression._BinaryExpression` object that records that this is a binary equality relation between the `name` column of the `users` table and a string literal that contains `spam`. When you convert this object to a string, you will get an SQL fragment like `users.name = :1`, where `:1` is a placeholder for the parameter. The `_BinaryExpression` object also remembers the binding of `:1` to `'spam'`, but it won't insert it until the SQL query is executed. When it is inserted, the database engine will make sure that it is properly escaped. Suggested reading: [SQLAlchemy's operator paradigm](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/sqlexpression.html#operators)

If you only have the database table but you don't have a `users` variable that describes the table, you can create it yourself:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, String, Boolean
metadata = MetaData()
users = Table('users', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String),
    Column('email', String),
    Column('active', Integer)
)
```

Alternatively, you can use autoloading which queries the database engine for the structure of the database and builds `users` automatically; obviously this is more time-consuming:

```
users = Table('users', metadata, autoload=True)
```

Comment: Any suggestions on where to look to figure out how I can create "valid and properly escaped SQL fragments" from a list of strings?

Comment: I searched the SQLAlchemy documentation for a while, but it looks like this is not really the proper way to do it with SQLAlchemy. Instead of building SQL fragments yourself, you should let SQLAlchemy build parameterised SQL queries using other methods from `sqlalchemy.sql`. I will extend my answer shortly to provide more details.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue in"[SQLAlchemy: an efficient/better select by primary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640628/sqlalchemy-an-efficient-better-select-by-primary-keys)":

```
terms = ['one', 'two', 'three']
clauses = or_( * [Table.field == x for x in terms] )
query = Session.query(Table).filter(clauses)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "[Conjunctions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/tutorial.html#conjunctions)" documentation to combine conditions `And`, `Or` and `not`.